# Toolbar height different on Lollipop

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

The app I'm working on uses [neokree's Material Navigation Drawer](https://github.com/neokree/MaterialNavigationDrawer) and it provides my toolbar with the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/statusBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/statusMargin"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statusBar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" />

</RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/layout_drawer" />
```

On my KitKat emulated devices, the toolbar shows up fine with a height of 56 dp. However, on Lollipop devices, it shows up twice as big with a height of 112 dp. Even when I hide the actionbar, a toolbar with a height of 56 dp remains.

Any reason why this would occur on Lollipop and not KitKat?

Comment: Are you defining actionBarSize in your theme? Is it defined differently in values-v21?

Comment: My theme has parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light"

Comment: 112dp in a smartphone?